# Webscraping using Selenium-YouTube Trending videos-selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to scrape YouTube Trending video details - video_title, vedio_url, channel name, and channel description using Selenium-python and requests libraries.

The youtube trending URL is:  https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending

I have identified the main container of videos

1 . I have successfully scraped video_title and title_url, But I was not able to scrape the channel name by the tag it displayed.

The sample code is this:

````
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
   from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   trending_videos_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending?bp=6gQJRkVleHBsb3Jl'
   chrome_driver_path = 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'


   # Create a ChromeService object with the executable path
  chrome_service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

   # Pass the service to the Chrome constructor using the service argument
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
   driver.get(trending_videos_url)
   print(driver.title)

   VIDEO_DIV_TAG = 'ytd-video-renderer'
   vedio_div = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,VIDEO_DIV_TAG)


   ## title , url , channel , views ,  uploaded , description
   vedio1 = vedio_div[0]

   def parse_vedio(vedio):
     title_tag = vedio.find_element(By.ID, 'video-title')
     title = title_tag.text
     url = title_tag.get_attribute('href')
     thumbnail_tag = vedio.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
     thumbnail_url = thumbnail_tag.get_attribute('src')
 

     channel_div = vedio.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'.yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string')

     channel_name = channel_div.text

     channel_desc_tag = vedio.find_element(By.ID, 'description-text')
     channel_desc = channel_desc_tag.text

     return {
       'title':title,
       'url': url,
       'thumbnail_img': thumbnail_url,
       'channel_name': channel_name,
       'channel_desc': channel_desc,
     }
   if __name__ == '__main__':
     print('parsing top 10 vedios')
     videos_data = [parse_vedio(vedio) for vedio in vedio_div[:10]]


     print(videos_data)```


  when i am trying to target the <a> TAG  with class name = ‘ yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-                      formatted-string ‘. I am getting the following error:nosuchelementexception


 



 I have tried with CUSTOM TAG <yt-formatted-string>,i was successful in scraping the channel name
````